# Multiply every other array element by 2

Tags: c#, arrays, indexof, modulus

I have an array of 10 digits. I want to multiply by 2, each element of the array with an even index. The elements with an odd index I want to multiply by 1 (in reality, leave unchanged). Hence, array[0] * 2, array[1] * 1, array[2] * 2, etc.

I tried using the modulus operator on the index number of each element, but I don't think that is what my code actually did. My previous silly attempt is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if ((Array.IndexOf(myArray, i) % 2) == 0)
    {
        // multiply myArray[i] by 2
    }
    else // multiply myArray[i] by 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if((i % 2) == 0)
    {
        // multiply myArray[i] by 2
    }
    else // multiply myArray[i] by 1
}
```

`Array.IndexOf(firstParam,secondParam)` will give you the index of secondParam. For example:

- arr[0] = 10
- arr[1] = 3
- arr[2] = 5
- arr[3] = 1

`Array.IndexOf(arr,1)` = 3, `Array.IndexOf(arr,3)` = 1, etc.

Comment: Oh...my... OK, this is why I should stop sitting in front of the computer for 8 hours straight. Thanks a lot for waking me up :)

Comment: No problem, it was a quickie for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

This code is for any no.of element in the list. (Array can have 1 or more element)

`myArray = myArray.Select(x => ((Array.IndexOf(myArray, x) % 2 == 0) ? x * 2 : x * 1)).ToArray();`

would give you the array of integers with even index element multiplied by 2, and odd on multipled by 1.